# Sql query - Distinct operation

Tags: php, sql

i try to solve a problem for me.
i have a index page and user enter start and end date.then a page is coming like that :

and query is that :

```
 $dbResult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profilesInitPlayer where Date BETWEEN '" . $startDate . "' and '" . $endDate . "'");
```

However what i want is to show dates only one times not every record. Can i do that distinct ? Or any other suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want just the different dates in the table (that are in the dates between your startdate and enddate)?

```
SELECT DISTINCT `Date`
FROM profilesInitPlayer ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to display all tuples in that date range but only print the day out once? you can't do that with SQL because the result of a sql statement is a 2D table and your desired structure would be something like a tree.

but you can do this with php. just `ORDER BY Date` in your query, loop over the tuples and every time you find a new Date, print it out:

```
$lastDate = false;
while($tuple = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    if ($tuple["Date"] != $lastDate)
    {
         print $tuple["Date"];
         $lastDate = $tuple["Date"];
    }
    var_dump($tuple);
}
```

this will produce something like

```
2012-02-20
tuple1
tuple2
tuple3
2012-02-21
tuple4
tuple5
```